# Node JS remote mysql database connection error

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am relatively new to the Node JS, and I have been trying to connect to a remote mysql server, but  I have been unable to do so. I have been looking for the solutions on here but most of them are for localhost.  Here is my code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "###.ipagemysql.com",
  user: "user",
  password: "mypass",
  database: "mydb",
  debug: true
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");

});
```

I am getting the error below:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 103.224.212.250:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)
```

UPDATE: 
I tried using a different MySQL server and that works fine. Could it be because iPage is blocking the connection because it is coming from a foreign machine? Is this something that can be configured in phpmyadmin?

Comment: have you checked the server connectivity on that port from your machine. try "telnet" to check if the connection is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly port 3306 is not accessible from the application. You can try telnet to server 103.224.212.250:3306 to see if it is opened or not.

Comment: It appears it is in fact closed. I tried using a different mysql server and that works fine. Could it be because iPage is blocking the connection because it is coming from a foreign machine? Is this something that can be configured in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Since you has not give more details on how you currently connect to you db server. There are 2 possibility: user config and server config. For user config, it may be declared as 'user'@'localhost', so that user is only accessible if it is in the same host with mysql server. Server config is if mysql server open port 3306 for accessing from outside, i.e firewall